# How to skew background with different color on each section

Tags: html, css, background, skew

So i'm looking to achieve something like this:
https://preview.ibb.co/fRidmR/example.jpg

So pretty much each color is a different div.Can it be done with only `CSS`? I tried a few things with `transform: skew`, but can't figure out how to make the one I want to be over the other and also the first one gets into the previous element each time.I tried with minus margin and more padding, but I want it responsive and it doesn't look good that way.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

best I can think of is could have a series of nested divs, each with a graphic background that has a transparent area to show the background of the div it is nested in.

So the html code would be like this:

```
<div id='grey_bg'>
<div id='red_skew'>
<div id='black_skew'>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and then have the css code like so:

```
#grey_bg{background: grey;}
#red_skew{background-image:url(red_skew.png);}
#black_skew{background-image:url(black_skew.png);}
```

Otherwise, just have a single bg image for the element.

Comment: Not working, i don't want to use bg image as a whole, cause i'm trying to make it responsive and because different text with different size should be fix in it.Like in some moment the second one may come bigger the others and same with the others.

Comment: I don't think what you are looking to do can be done with CSS and HTML alone. Neither CSS nor HTML supports any sort of drawing function to allow you to 'draw' anything other then squares. While the transform functions allow you to rotate and deform those squares, that's not what you're looking to do. Everything I can think off shy of full interactive programming with flash or java would require you to use graphics.